# Error Handling. Display error when attempting to withdraw more money then the account holds

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a simple banking program where I can create an account, and deposit and withdraw money from the account.

I'm having issues getting my code to display my error messages when:

1. I try to withdraw more money than I have.
2. Withdrawing money when I are already have a negative balance.

When withdrawing from an account that already has insufficient funds, it should prompt with the `InsufficientFundsError`. And When I make a negative withdrawal it should prompt wht the `NegativeAmountError`.

This is the class File:

```
class BankAccount
  @@id = 0

  def initialize( name )
    @id = @@id = (@@id + 1)
    @name = name
    @balance = 0
  end

  def deposit( amount )
    @balance += amount if amount > 0
  end

  def withdraw( amount )
    @balance = @balance - amount

  end

  def to_s
    "Account #@id - Balance: #@balance (#@name)"
  end
end


class InsufficientFundsError < BankAccount
  def initialize( id, balance, amount )

  end

  def to_s
     "Account #{@id} has insufficient funds ($#{@balance}) to allow the withdrawal of $#{amount}"
  end
end

class NegativeAmountError < BankAccount
  def initialize( action, id )

  end

  def to_s
  "You cannot [action] a negative amount for account [id]"
  end
end
```

And the Driver file:

```
require_relative "bankaccount" 

accounts = []

choice = 1

until choice == 5
    puts "1. Open A Account Account"
    puts "2. View you Accounts"
    puts "3. Make A Deposit"
    puts "4. Make A Withdrawal"
    puts "5. Exit The Peoples Champ Bank"

    print "What Business would you like to take care of today? Choose one: "
    choice = gets.to_i

    case choice

    when 1 ;
        if accounts.size < 6
            print "What will the name of this account be? "
            name = gets.chomp
            accounts.push( BankAccount.new name )
            puts "The Account has been created"
        else
            puts "You have exceeded the maximum number of accounts"
        end

    when 2 ;
        accounts.each_with_index {|a, i| puts "#{i}. #{a}"}
    when 3 ;
        begin
            print "What is the deposit amount? "
            amount = gets.to_i
            accounts.each_with_index {|a, i| puts "#{i}. #{a}"}
            print "Which account would like to depositing to? "
            accounts[ gets.to_i ].deposit( amount )
        rescue NegativeAmountError => e
            puts e.to_s
        end

    when 4 ;
        begin
            print "How much would you like to withdraw? "
            amount = gets.to_i
            accounts.each_with_index {|a, i| puts "#{i}. #{a}"}
            print "Which account would you like to withdraw from? "
            accounts[ gets.to_i ].withdraw( amount )
        rescue InsufficientFundsError => e
            puts e.to_s
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used `begin`/`rescue`/`end` correctly, but it doesn't look like you're actually checking for the error conditions and raising the exceptions.

For instance:

```
def withdraw(amount)
  if @balance - amount < 0
    raise InsufficientFundsError.new(@id, @balance, amount)
  end
  @balance = @balance - amount
end
```

Also, your exceptions should subclass `Exception`:

```
class InsufficientFundsError << Exception
```

Comment: when trying to withdraw more money then what i have i am receiving the error ` C:/Users/Phillip/Desktop/bankaccount.rb:16:in `raise': exception class/object expected (TypeError)
        from C:/Users/Phillip/Desktop/School Fall 2013/Ruby/Homework/Lab07/bankaccount.rb:16:in `withdraw'
        from lab07.rb:45:in `<main>' ` If i have 300 and subtract 100 it does the math with no issue but when im subtracting 300 from 100 or anything over higher than what i have i get the error.